# how can I click on the last HTML element which has the same textlink/xpath values? I tried using the [last()] function, no luck

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, click

I am using the following:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@title='linkname'])[last()]")).click();
```

some help would be appreciated... I just want to click the last HTML element on the page which has SAME xpath and name to the link, I am not sure what's wrong here....

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this without XPath, you can just grab the collection of elements and click the last one.

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@title='linkname']));
inputs.get(inputs.size() - 1).click();
```